# Выполнение действия при клике на кнопку оповещения, когда приложение закрыто. Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Имеется ли возможность сделать действие, при клике на кнопку оповещения, без запуска приложения?

Я смотрю примеры, и везде нужно указать Penging Intent, в котором нужно указать Activity, которое будет запущено

```
 mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_push)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setTicker(message)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_delete_white, "Завершить", pendingIntentClose)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_archive_white, "Подробности", pendingIntentDetails)

            .setAutoCancel(true)
```

Comment: Можно упаковать еще Service и Broadcast

Comment: @Style-7 ну а вообще без запуска? мне нужно просто отправить запрос в сеть и все на завершение заказа и все

Comment: Ну что значит без запуска? Вы запустите сервис или пошлете сигнал вашему приемнику а там делайте что хотите.

Comment: Делайте через Service.